# My son with autism. Or say" My son has autism" or "my son is autistic"?

Tags: expressions

My family of 4 is going to travel next month.

Is it correct? Or a better way to say it?

1.（ in a restaurant）

Sorry, My son with autism. （Or say My son has autism" or "my son is autistic"?）
We don’t want to bother people, could we sit at（or in？） the corner/ take the corner seat？

2.（ in a line）

Sorry, My son with autism, he doesn’t speak（or talk? nonverbal）.

Could you do me a favor, please let me go ahead of you in the line?

3.（in a zoo）

Sorry, My son with autism.

Do you offer a concession ticket/have any discount for the disabled people?

4.（in a bus or public area）

My son with autism, he screams sometimes, please don’t mind. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 4):

From a purely grammatical perspective, "my son **is autistic**" and "my son **has autism**" are both correct forms. Both work as a single-sentence explanation.

"My son **with autism**" would not be a complete sentence, and while it could work as an opening phrase to a sentence, it sounds a bit clunky. "My son with autism doesn't speak" would be better phrased as "My **autistic** son doesn't speak" or "My son, **who has autism**, doesn't speak."

The difference between "autistic" and "has autism" gets into a longer, sociological discussion about "person-first language." This is a heavily debated topic within the autistic community and other disabled communities, and there is no single correct answer. I would say in the US, "autistic" is the preferred form, instead of "has autism". But this varies in different parts of the country and certainly in different countries. Neither form is offensive.

In the US, it's also common to hear "[my son is] **on the autism spectrum**" or simply "[my son is] **on the spectrum**." This may be a way to sidestep the "autistic"/"has autism" problem.

[There's an interesting article from the Autistic Self Advocacy Network about the debate here](https://autisticadvocacy.org/about-asan/identity-first-language/), with links to a number of articles on both sides of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are a family of four and we're going traveling next month.
OR (If it is you, your partner and two children):
We're going traveling next month with our two children.

1.（in a restaurant）

Excuse me (OR Sorry). My son is autistic and we don’t want to bother people. Could we possibly sit in the corner?
OR
Could we possibly take the corner seats?

2.（in a line）

Sorry. My son is autistic. He doesn’t speak.
Could you possibly do me a favor and let us go ahead of you in the line?
OR
I would really appreciate it (I'd be very grateful) if you'd let us go ahead of you in the line.

3.（in a zoo）

Sorry. My son is autistic.
Do you offer a concession ticket?
OR
Is there a discount for disabled people?

4.（in a bus or public area）

My son has autism. He sometimes screams. Please ignore it. I am so sorry.

Comment: The OP appears to be learning US English. Please correct anything that sounds too British. (Although - if they're visiting the UK...)